# Images show as white squares when debugging Xcode with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode

I've had this problem a few times before. Every time I debug my app (made in xcode with swift) a varied assortment of the images will just load as white squares and then the app will eventually crash.

Last time I fixed it by having to remove every single image and add them all again.

- It's different images that it happens to every time.
- This was not happening yesterday but as soon as I opened the xcode project today it started after changing basically nothing (no new images added, no new code etc.)
- It's not an issue with using too much memory, etc.
- I have no clue why it's happening again or how to fix it.
- It is also happening to some sound resources, they just don't load and cause the game to crash.

Comment: Its happen sometime..try to view in Preview tab... i think you will see image in that tab...!!

Comment: Nothing in the debug console to help with this question? Have you tried cleaning your app and re-running it? What about on a device?

Comment: It happens on every simulator, and on my device. Even after cleaning, reinstalling. This bug once accidentally made it into a release version, every one I spoke to with the app was experiencing it.

Comment: So nobody has any clue at all what the hell is going on?
How can this only happen to me? I haven't even done anything to cause it

Comment: Today I tried what I did last time, removing every asset and adding them all manually again. It did not work. I am desperate for a fix now, even just some ideas.

Comment: UPDATE: It is also saying in the console, error loading sound resource "example", anderror loading sprite resource "example". (For what ever things are being white squares.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR LOADING FILES IN XCODE 7.2 AND CRASHING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675030/error-loading-files-in-xcode-7-2-and-crashing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this and answered it in my other related question.

[Here's the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675030/error-loading-files-in-xcode-7-2-and-crashing)