# ERROR LOADING FILES IN XCODE 7.2 AND CRASHING

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just started working on a new version of my app. I opened the project and ran the game on the simulator and got constant errors in the debug console.
"sound file could not be loaded "example.wav"" and the same with images.

- I changed nothing at all, however I believe I got an XCode update just before I started on this. (To version 7.2)
- I also get the same problem after numerous days of testing, on every simulator and device. The images and sounds that it lists do not display/play, sprites instead display as white squares.
- After a faulty image/sound has been loaded (ie. a white square has appeared) if it is interacted with or if the scene changes the app will crash.

What the heck is going on?

Comment: Can you show us the code that raises this error?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I JUST figured it out, but if you or anyone else are interested, it said. "Error loading sound file: "lick.mp3". It also blamed a few other files but I narrowed it down to that one. I will answer the question fully in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason I was getting all the many errors.
Firstly a lot of them were random (harmless) XCode 7.2 errors, but the errors that were causing the crashing and incorrect loading of files were caused by:
I was accidentally loading a sound file in the Update function. I moved this out of that void and it began working perfectly. It must've been loading over and over and causing the error.